# Displaying movieclips from an array in sequential order

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Establish an array of movie clips in the library
2. Randomize the order within the array
3. On enter frame, display the first movie clip in the randomized array
4. When a "next" button is clicked, the existing clip with unload and the next move clip in the array order will load
5. Once the last movie clip in the array has been displayed and the "next" button  has been clicked, the first movie clip in the array will load.
6. this will repeat over and over if the user keeps clicking the "next" button.

Here is the code that I have so far that establishes the random array:

```
var animalArray:Array = ["animal1","animal2","animal3","animal4","animal5","animal6","animal7",]; 
var animalIndex:int = -1; 

function getNextanimal():String {
    if(animalIndex == -1) animalIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * (animalArray.length - 1)); 

    animalIndex++; //increment it
    if(animalIndex >= animalArray.length) animalIndex = 0; 

    return animalArray[animalIndex];
}
```

this is the code for my button:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickCard);
function clickCard(event: MouseEvent): void {

    var animalCard: String = getNextanimal();
    addChild(animalCard);

}
```

I only get errors when clicking the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't look at your code yet, but it's usually helpful to post the errors and which lines they correspond to.

Comment: Though I can tell you right away that you can't use `addChild` with a string as the parameter.  Do you have a items in your library with AS3 linkage id's that match that array of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this:

```
//create your array (nothing changed here, though you could do this in a loop if all items follow a numerical pattern like it appears they do)
var animalArray:Array = ["animal1", "animal2", "animal3", "animal4", "animal5", "animal6", "animal7", ];

//create a function that randomizes the array:
function randomSort(a:*, b:*):int {
    return ( Math.random() > .5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}

//sort the array using the function above   
animalArray.sort(randomSort);

//copy the array so you can reset it after getting to the end of a cycle
var origArray:Array = animalArray.concat();

//get the next animal
function getNextAnimal():String {
    //if the array is now empty, copy the original array (you could also re-randomize here if desired)
    if (!animalArray.length) animalArray = origArray.concat();

    //pop takes the last item of the array (and removes it from the array)
    return(animalArray.pop());
}
```

---

Now, the error you're encountering is likely the result of trying to use `addChild` with a string as the parameter (it's expecting a display object).

If these animals are actually instance names, just use `getChildByName`:

```
addChild(getChildByName(getNextAnimal));
```

If they are linkage ID's exported from your library, then use they're actual class names instead of strings in your array, then instantiate them:

```
var animalArray:Array = [Animal1, Animal2, Animal3, Animal4];

//then later:
function getNextAnimal():Class  ...

//then later:
var cls:Class = getNextAnimal();
addChild(new cls());
```

---

So, your next click should look something like this:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickCard);    
var curItem:DisplayObject; //you need a var to keep track of the last item added

function clickCard(event: MouseEvent): void {
    //if there is a current item and it has a parent, remove it
    if(curItem && curItem.parent) removeChild(curItem);
    var cls:Class = getNextAnimal();
    curItem = new cls();
    addChild(curItem);
}
```

---

### EDIT

Knowing that your are using Linkage ID's, this is how I'd write this:

```
//a vector is just like an array, except all members have to be of the specified type
var animalArray:Vector.<Class> = new <Class>[animal1, animal2, animal3];

function randomSort(a:*, b:*):int {
    return ( Math.random() > .5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}

animalArray.sort(randomSort);
var origArray:Vector.<Class> = animalArray.concat();

function getNextAnimal():Class {
    if (!animalArray.length) animalArray = origArray.concat();
    return(animalArray.pop());
}

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickCard);    
var curItem:DisplayObject; //a var to keep track of the last item added

function clickCard(event: MouseEvent): void {
    //if there is a current item and it has a parent, remove it
    if(curItem && curItem.parent) removeChild(curItem);
    var cls:Class = getNextAnimal();
    curItem = new cls();
    addChild(curItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I am linkage IDs for the movieclips. Therefore i have tried to apply your suggestion above.  However, i get this error when testing: "Method cannot be used as a constructor" on the line containing addChild(new getNextAnimal());

Comment: I updated the code near the end of the answer with something you can try (I don't have flash pro handy at the moment to test).  Also, make sure your array contains classes and not strings, and that the getNextAnimal function returns a Class and not a string.

Comment: Go it. After modifying with your suggestions, I am now getting the following error when i click the button:  TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert animal2@16592a2bdba1 to Class.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an object called `animal2` somewhere?  Are you sure your linkage ID's match what's in your array Exactly?

Comment: Everything is working now.  Had to fix the linkage IDs. Thanks!!