# Errors when loading random movie clips from an array as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am getting closer to finding a solution for the errors being generated when running the code below.

I have three boxes on the stage.  The goal is to load one random item from the array without any one item being duplicated in more than one of the three boxes.

Yasuyuki Uno has been very helpful.  We are currently trying to solve the following:

Code:

```
var animalArray: Array = [animal1, animal2, animal3, animal4, animal5, animal6, animal7, animal8, animal9, animal10];
var randArr: Array = [];
var rand: int;

// Get random value for 3 times.
for(var i:int=0,len:int=animalArray.length;i<3;i++,len--){
    rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * len); // Generate random integer between 0 and len-1.
    randArr.push(animalArray.splice(rand,1)); // Delete a value from original array and add that value to new array.
}

box1.addChild(randArr[0]);
box2.addChild(randArr[1]);
box3.addChild(randArr[2]);
```

> Error Message: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thnx!

Comment: Your code looks fine and that error is not fired from that posted code. Try to debug your app to get the exact line of the error.

Comment: Exact line of error occurs at: box1.addChild(randArr[0]);

I changed to: addChild(randArr[0]);

And now get the error: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@b41ac25bc41 to flash.display.DisplayObject.

Comment: You got that error because `animalArray.splice()` is returning an array, so you have to push the object to the `randArr` array then remove it from your `animalArray` one using `splice()`.

Comment: I am working with it a bit per your reccomendation.  I tried randArr.push(animalArray[rand]); and i get the Coercion error again, however it is more specific: cannot convert  animal2$ to flash.display.DisplayObject

Comment: As @akmozo said splice returns an array, so change the code `animalArray.splice(rand,1)` to `animalArray.splice(rand,1)[0]`.

Comment: Seeing [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706217/displaying-movieclips-from-an-array-in-sequential-order), it seems that you are using linkage ID.
Sorry, but I don't know about it.

Comment: Make sure "animal2" is a disaply object?

Comment: @Warren What is `animal1`, `animal2`, etc? They are linkage IDs in your library?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `animal1`, `animal2`, etc are linkage IDs in your library, they are class references so they need to be instantiated using the `new` operator.

There are a few other non-critical issues with your code that made it hard to understand from my point of view:

- Using `animal1` instead of `Animal1` and so on for class names. Uncapitalized names look like properties or functions, not classes.
- Using `Array` instead of [`Vector`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html). Vectors give you better errors; had you been using Vectors from the start your problem would be obvious.

Example:

```
var animalTypes:Vector.<Class> = new <Class>[Animal1, Animal2, Animal3, Animal4, Animal5, Animal6, Animal7, Animal8, Animal9, Animal10];

var randomAnimals:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new <DisplayObject>[];

// Get random value for 3 times.
for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++){
    // Generate random integer between 0 and length-1.
    var randomIndex:int = Math.random() * animalTypes.length; 
    // Remove a class from original vector.
    var randomAnimalType:Class = animalTypes.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0]; 
    // Create an instance of the animal class.
    var randomAnimal:DisplayObject = new randomAnimalType(); 
    // Add the instance to the random vector.
    randomAnimals.push(randomAnimal); 
}

box1.addChild(randomAnimals[0]);
box2.addChild(randomAnimals[1]);
box3.addChild(randomAnimals[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you check `length` of animalArray in for expression, it's no need to change variable `len`.
Also if you want to fill with 3 random items new array, you need to use this code:

```
const arr: Array = [animal1, animal2, animal3, animal4, animal5, animal6, animal7];
const genArr: Array = [];

var len: int = arr.length;
var n: int = 3;
while(n--) {
    const randIndex: int = Math.floor(Math.random()*len); // get random index

    genArr.push(arr.splice(randIndex, 1)[0]); // splice returns array, so we need first and exist item
    len--; // decrement length as optimized solution of no-read length of array each cycle
}

trace(genArr);
```

Comment: You've re-written a `for` loop as a `while` loop but it works exactly the same way as before (the original `for` loop was not reading `length` each iteration, and even if it was that's not a performance concern here.) Also, the use of `const` for `arr`, `genArr` and `randIndex` is questionable, since this code changes those values multiple times.

Comment: @Aaron, Didn't saw 2nd variable `length` init. 
Using optimisation practices in writing your code – says promising attitude, reliable code and experience. If you have good tone – always give the best view of code as you can make. About `const` declaration in as3 is question of your experience and knowledge of language.